# Joomla Pagination Issue. Last page browsed is automatically shown as default page in the list view without pagination in same browser

Tags: pagination

Joomla displaying wrong pagination

To explain with

a) say i am on page 24 the page shows below url

```
/index.php?option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=10&limitstart=115
```

b) Now when the com news list page opened / browsed again on the same browser

```
/index.php?option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=10
```

It displays content of page 24

However - when the page is tried and accessed on new browser - its displayed correctly

The cache is disabled, This is checked on chrome, firefox - all same

Basically any last page (say page 20) as browsed by user when explored in list view and again shown as default page in this url

```
/index.php?option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=10
```

This is browser

The first page has to manually be selected through
How to solve it

Am on joomla 3.6.2, apache 2.4, php 5.6

**Edited** 
Though this is solved by destroying joomla session variable

```
<?php $session = JFactory::getSession(); $session->destroy();
```

Unsure how well is it
Is there a way to kill only pagination session only

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a caching issue. Either you have the "System - Cache" plugin enabled, or you have some aggressive caching at the server level (if you are on a shared host, then note that some hosts are recently much more aggressive in their caching for shared hosting accounts).

Also, try renaming your `.htaccess` file to see if the problem is caused by some rules in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @ itoctopus - as checked the issue only pertains to same user in the same browser. Question edited, any thoughts - cache is disabled

Comment: Are you using any type of SEF? This problem can be caused by sh404SEF.

Comment: No its not by sh404sef as i am not using it, however i could find out that something related to session variable of joomla. As when i use `<?php
$session = JFactory::getSession(); 
$session->destroy();` - it works correctly. Is using session destroy a correct menthod

Answer (score 1):

Open your actual Breadcrumbs module and make sure the caching is disabled there as well.

Comment: @ YellowWebMonkey - How to check if cache is disabled in it. I have re-edited the question as issue is with same user in same browser

Comment: Not sure if I understand your reply, I apologize if I am misreading.  If you are asking how to check the individual module, go to Module Manager, open that specific mod_breadcrumbs, go to Advanced tab, and check Caching: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1493125/fe724689793b5e898d03c48cc707a1d9